# What is this purplish-pink succulent?

Tags: identification, succulents

I have this nice purplish-pink succulent that I potted up into a dark-soiled, well-drained medium in a black pot about two weeks ago. I purchased this from a market that never specified its name. Does anyone know what it is and how to care for it?
[image]

[image]

Comment: I would guess its the common "jade plant" *crassula ovata,* but it has been grown in bright sunlight and lost its dark green color because it didn't need to produce much chlorophyll for photosynthesis. Keep it out of direct sunlight and it will gradually turn back to its normal "jade" colour.

Comment: I'm not too sure if this is a jade plant, as it has somewhat of a pink pigmentation on the surface as well. I've added another photo with perhaps a clearer view.

Comment: I agree it's not a jade plant, now we have a better picture. But *crassulaceae*  was half right :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its Graptopetalum amethystinum (Rose), previously known as Pachyphytum, images here http://www.crassulaceae.ch/de/artikel?akID=55&aaID=2&aiID=A&aID=82.

Care instructions are more or less the same as for Jade plant if kept as a houseplant; average warmth from spring to autumn (though they do appreciate cooler night time temperatures), Keep cool in winter - 50-60 degrees F is ideal. Place on a windowsill if possible so it gets some sun, but some shade from hot sun in summer is advisable. Water when the surface of the soil is just dry to the touch, watering well and emptying out any that remains on the tray beneath after 30 minutes; reduce watering significantly in winter, watering only every 1-2 months. They do appreciate a bit of air, so an open window in the vicinity will provide that. Repot only when essential, preferably in spring and preferably into a relatively shallow pot - the one you've used looks a little too deep really. These plants don't have deep roots, so that means a lot of unoccupied, wet/damp potting soil in the pot which will increase the risk of possible fungal problems.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed information! I tend to agree with this ID. Will make sure to watch for and try to prevent fungal problems and watch out for watering frequency.